# Express Session on Node js with Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am writing a nodejs backend application for an application I developed with Vue. I need to create sessions for users' db operations and select databases according to the user. I wanted to use express-session for this, but the sessions I created are seen as undefined in different requests. How can I overcome this problem? I use history mode on Vue so my requests must go through the router for now. Also I can convey that I am open to alternative suggestions.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const productRequest = require("./controllers/products/products")
const customerRequest = require("./controllers/customers/customers")
const orderRequest = require("./controllers/orders/orders")
const controllerRequest = require("./controllers/controllers")
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
var session = require('express-session')
const cors = require("cors")

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
app.use('/products', productRequest)
app.use('/orders', orderRequest)
app.use('/customers', customerRequest)
app.use('/controllers', controllerRequest)
module.exports = app;
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const controllers = express.Router();
const login = require('./login.js')
const userkey = require("./userkey");

controllers.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    login(req.body, response => {
        if (response[0].total == 0) {
            res.status(204).json({
                message: "Fail",
                result: null
            })
        } else if (response[0].total == 1) {

            /* SESSION SETTED HERE  */
            req.session.corp = response[0].corp
            console.log(req.session.corp)
            /* HERE SEEMS CREATED */
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Connected",
                result: response
            })
        }
    })
});
controllers.post("/userkey", (req, res, next) => {

    /* CANT USE HERE response UNDEFINED*/
    console.log(req.session.corp)
    userkey([req.body, req.session.corp], response => {
        res.status(200).json({
            data: response
        })
    })
});
module.exports = controllers;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some massive headaches with sessions and would have kept going until I read

> *Also I can convey that I am open to alternative suggestions.*

Please then consider using [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

as simple as this :

```js
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
```

The [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package is simple to use and should match your needs.

Comment: i ll use it. Thanks.